# Add class to Woocommerce out-of-stock product cards - using Hestia theme

Tags: class, woocommerce, product, addition, card

I am using Hestia Wordpress Theme, and I am trying to add a class "out-of-stock" to product cards that meet that condition. I have tried some functions, but without success.

The product card looks like this:

```
<div class="card card-product pop-and-glow">                                                            
<div class="card-image">
    ... content of card-image ...
</div>
<div class="content">
    ... here comes content ...              
</div>
</div>
```

I would like to have something like this when the product is out-of-stock:

```
<div class="card card-product pop-and-glow out-of-stock">                                                           
<div class="card-image">
    ... content of card-image ...
</div>
<div class="content">
    ... here comes content ...              
</div>
</div>
```

Any hint would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot
R-)

Comment: This is the website: https://www.LoMo.com.br. Tks.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec could you help me on this one? Thanks!